# How to get a dependency tree for an artifact?

Tags: maven-2, build-process, dependencies

`dependency:tree` can be used to see the dependency tree for a given project. But what I need is to see the dependency tree for a 3rd party artifact.

I guess I can create an empty project, but I'm looking for something easier (I need to do this for several artifacts).

Comment: If you happen to need to do this *programmatically* from within *a plugin* (not exactly the *hierarchy* but the full *collection* of transitive dependencies - honoring dependencyManagement, exclusions etc), [check this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200497/how-to-programmatically-list-all-transitive-dependencies-including-overridden-o#70823705)

Answer (score 408, accepted):

#### 1) Use [maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html)

Create a simple project with `pom.xml` only. Add your dependency and run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

(Version for multi-module Maven project: `mvn compile dependency:tree` )

Unfortunately [dependency mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) must use `pom.xml` or you get following error:

> Cannot execute mojo: tree. It requires a project with an existing `pom.xml`, but the build is not using one.

#### 2) Find `pom.xml` of your artifact in maven central repository

Dependencies are described In `pom.xml` of your artifact. Find it using maven infrastructure.

Go to https://central.sonatype.com and enter your `groupId` and `artifactId`.

Or you can go to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ and navigate first using plugins `groupId`, later using `artifactId` and finally using its version.

For example see [org.springframework:spring-core](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.3.RELEASE/)

#### 3) Use maven dependency plugin against your artifact

Part of dependency artifact is a `pom.xml`. That specifies it's dependency. And you can execute `mvn dependency:tree` on this pom.

Comment: Like I said, I want to avoid the need to create a project

Comment: you're not 'creating' a project, you're just downloading a POM file.

Comment: You don't have to create a new project. Just take a look into your local repository and find the atifact's pom.xml

Comment: This does not work if the child module does not exist. e.g.
```
mvn -f  ~/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-parent/2.0.0-alpha-10/shrinkwrap-descriptors-parent-2.0.0-alpha-10.pom depen
dency:tree
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
    [ERROR] Child module ~/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-parent/2.0.0-alpha-10/api-base of .../descriptors-parent/2.0.0-alpha-10/shrinkwrap-descriptors-parent-2.0.0-alpha-10.pom does not exist
```

Comment: Try to edit the particular pom file and temporary comment the missing submodule.

Comment: Also to copy to a particular folder 
$ mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=OUTPUT_DIR

Comment: For multi-module Maven project (i.e. project with several `pom.xml` files) you might get error. Try `mvn compile dependency:tree` then.

Answer (score 99):

If you bother creating a sample project and adding your 3rd party dependency to that, then you can run the following in order to see the full hierarchy of the dependencies.

You can search for a specific **artifact** using this maven command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]
```

According to the documentation:

> where each pattern segment is optional and supports full and partial * wildcards. An empty pattern segment is treated as an implicit wildcard.

Imagine you are trying to find 'log4j-1.2-api' jar file among different modules of your project:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api
```

more information can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).

**Edit:** The **verbose** flag has been reintroduced in version [3.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-644).
You can use the specific version as below:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree -Dverbose=true
```

Comment: Great suggestion! `-Dverbose` was enough to show me the full tree I needed. Piping the output to `less` or similar and doing a quick search works great if you can't remember the `includes` flag or don't want to provide the full or wildcarded `groupId` :)

Comment: This isn't working without a pom.xml present that contains the artefact you are looking at. 

Otherwise you get `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (...). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: -Dverbose has been deprecated in the dependency plugin, so this does not work anymore unless you're using a pretty old version.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice answer. Does `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.17.1` in the result mean log4j version 1 or 2?

Comment: @mercury This is  Log4j 1.x Compatibility API. This bridge  allows applications coded to use Log4j 1.2 API to use Log4j 2 instead.

Comment: @toolforger Can you please share the latest option for -Dverbose?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar unfortunately, the option was simply removed without a replacement. You'll have to go into the dependency:tree documentation to find out if it has been reintroduced in some form since 2020, I don't have the time to check.

Answer (score 20):

The solution is to call dependency:tree with the artifact's pom.xml file:

```
mvn -f "$HOME/.m2/repository/$POM_PATH" dependency:tree
```

See also [How to list the transitive dependencies of an artifact from a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355688/how-to-list-the-transitive-dependencies-of-an-artifact-from-a-repository)

Comment: This might not work with artifacts downloaded from a central repository, because of 'distributionManagement.status'. It is added by the central repository on upload. And this will make dependency:tree fail validation on the pom file. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3178

Answer (score 16):

If anyone using **IntelliJ** wants to see dependency tree directly in IDE then they can install [Maven Helper Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper) plugin.

Once installed open pom.xml and you would able to see **Dependency Analyze** tab like below. It also provides option to see dependency that is conflicted only and also as a tree structure.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The [for-artifact](https://ferstl.github.io/depgraph-maven-plugin/for-artifact-mojo.html) goal of the [depgraph-maven-plugin](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin/) should do what you want. To get a dependency graph of `org.jboss.ws:jbossws-common-tools:1.3.2.Final` you simply do

```
mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:3.3.0:for-artifact -DgroupId=org.jboss.ws -DartifactId=jbossws-common-tools -Dversion=1.3.2.Final -DgraphFormat=text -DshowGroupIds=true -DshowVersions=true
```

and you get

```
org.jboss.ws:jbossws-common-tools:1.3.2.Final:compile
+- org.jboss.ws:jbossws-api:1.1.2.Final:compile
+- org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.1:provided
|  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.7.1:provided
+- gnu.getopt:java-getopt:1.0.13:provided
+- log4j:log4j:1.2.14:provided
\- junit:junit:3.8.2:test
```

without the need to create a Maven project or use and IDE or online app.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a current version of [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) (which you should if you use eclipse and maven):

Select the menu entry

`Navigate -> Open Maven POM`

and enter the artifact you are looking for.

The pom will open in the pom editor, from which you can select the tab `Dependency Hierarchy` to view the dependency hierarchy (as the name suggests :-) )

Answer (score 5):

When using IntelliJ, you have a one-click tool for Maven dependency exploration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html

Results:
[image]

Comment: For Intellij: Open the Maven Panel, find your project, right click -> Show Dependencies

Answer (score 4):

You can filter a specific artifact using the -Dincludes flag:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=<artifact>
```

You can find more information [here](https://devwithus.com/maven-dependency-tree/)

Answer (score 1):

If your artifact is not a dependency of a given project, your best bet is to use a [repository search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192050/how-do-i-find-out-apache-buildr-maven-2-repo-names). Many of them describes the dependencies of a given artifact.

Comment: the artifacts i'm interested in are part of a company product

Comment: then amra's answer is your best bet, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a local repository use -s settings.xml along with it. Below is what worked for me:

```
mvn clean compile install -s settings.xml
mvn dependency:tree -s settings.xml
```