# How can I view transitive dependencies of a Maven pom.xml file?

Tags: maven-2, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Is there a CLI tool I can use to quickly view the transitive dependencies of a Maven `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a dependency tree for an artifact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342908/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-for-an-artifact)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

On the CLI, use [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)
(Here are some additional [Usage notes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#The_dependency:tree_Mojo))

When running `dependency:tree` on multi-module maven project, use `mvn compile dependency:tree` instead<sup>1</sup>.

Otherwise, the POM Editor in [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) (Maven integration for Eclipse) is very good, and it includes a hierarchical dependency view.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>If you don't compile, you might get error `Failed to execute goal on project baseproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:childproject:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact`. This might happen because `dependency:tree` command doesn't build projects and doesn't resolve dependencies, and your projects are not installed in maven repository.</sup>

Comment: That's not really practical if you're trying to identify which transitive dependencies you are relying on at compile time. It just gives you a giant list of all transitive dependencies, used or not.

Comment: Also, to see conflict resolution among transitive dependencies, you will need to add verbose: mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose 
``https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html``

Comment: I think the verbose option suggested by @kisna is essential - otherwise, repeated transitive dependencies will not be drawn.

Comment: Another caveat: if a project uses the Shade plugin, `dependency:tree` may not be able to draw its transitive dependencies.