# I have build apk file from Android Studio but at time to upload on playstore I have following error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, android-install-apk

We rejected  project, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher.

But I am not adding any libpng library in my project.How to resolve this issue??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: share your decencies list.

Comment: that dependency might be used by one of the dependencies you use

Comment: librabies in project are as follows:                                                        1. LeopardProwessSdkV-1.1.6                                                                         2. ImageSupport-V1.5                                                                                        3. core-3.2.0                                                                                                          4. org-apache-commons-codec                                                                              5. ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies

Comment: probably some of the libraries you are using have dependancy to `libpng`

Comment: Thanks  Vladyslav Matviienko ..I have searched but unable to find out in which library libpng in used.

Comment: we can't help you as you didn't show the list of libraries you use

Comment: Vladyslav Matviienko ,I already mention the list of libraries that I have used in my application

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added it directly, it is likely that one of your dependencies did. In software engineering these are often called "transitive dependencies". Now, it can be a little hard to see what libraries your dependencies are using. But there are a few things you can do:

- if you get your dependencies from source, look at their gradle/makefile/maven files to see the dependencies. Repeat going down looking at their dependencies and so on
- LibPNG is almost certainly to do with processing PNG files. So it is much more likely that a dependency called something like ImageSupport has this as a dependency
- If your project uses Maven you can trace the transitive dependency tree as answered [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110782/how-can-i-view-transitive-dependencies-of-a-maven-pom-xml-file)
- If your project uses gradle you can see dependencies with the [`gradle dependencies` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288133/what-is-the-gradle-artifact-dependency-graph-command) as answered here on stackoverflow
- If all else fails you can always unzip the jars/APKs of the dependencies and look for a file called something like "libpng.so"

Comment: I have tried above mentioned points plus all possiblities on google ,also added external library of letest libpng  but still facing the same problem.Is there any another solution