# Junit throwing java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status

Tags: mockito, response, junit4

Currently am writing Junit for our webservice code.

WebService Code and Junit code is written in the code section

When I run the Junit am getting the below error

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(Response.java:921)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:592)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:603)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok(Response.java:638)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok(Response.java:650)
at com.renault.rntbci.stl.service.demande.impl.ListDemandServiceImpl.getDemandeListCount(ListDemandServiceImpl.java:281)
at com.renault.rntbci.stl.service.demande.impl.ListDemandeTest.testGetDemandeListCount(ListDemandeTest.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

One of my friend advised me to change the scope to test in pom.xml for jax rs version as below.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

But still the same error is persisting. Kindly anyone please help me with a solution.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Note:
This is an existing application and I am new to this project which is with Java 1.7

```java
public Response someMethod(String stringValue){

    Map<String, Long> outputMap = new TreeMap<String, Long>();

    try {
        Long outputValue = service.getCount(stringValue);
        //this call goes to a service and gets the db count for a table
        outputMap.put("listCount", outputValue);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage(), e); 
    }
    return Response.ok(outputMap).build();
}
```

And Junit code is

```java
@Mock
Service service;

@Mock
Response res;
@Test
public void testSomeMethod() throws SQLException {
    String stringValue="12";
    Long returnValue=10L;

    when(service.getCount(stringValue)).thenReturn(returnValue);
    res=obj.someMethod(stringValue);
    Assert.assertNotNull(res);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Comment: No am using resteasy

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using an IDE. Would you try to find your class in your project (searching non-project files)? Is it coming from more than one JAR file? Is `javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder` coming from two different JAR files? I suspect that you are actually using two different versions of RestEasy due to a diamond dependency issue, but don't have enough info to confirm that.

Comment: I saw the following jax rs dependencies in the pom.xml file<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
   <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>                                                                              And this one as well.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that what's happening here is that you have two different versions of the JAR file containing the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder` class. Between the two versions of this class that you have floating around, the abstract `status()` method changed. You need to go through your list of Maven dependencies by running the `mvn dependency:tree` command as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110881/4851565). You need to identify the two different JAR versions containing the two different `javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder` classes. Exclude the dependency version you don't want and keep the version you do want to keep.

It could be as simple as deleting the `jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec` Jar file but depending on what other dependencies you have (and which transitive dependencies) there may be more to it than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot entpnerd. I will try the same and will update you.