# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-2.0, abstractmethoderror

Anyone saw similar error before? I looked into `maven` dependencies and it looks I am using `jersey 2.26`. So, I don't think it is dependency conflict issue. The `ResponseBuilder` is not recognizing the method status.

From other posts, I understand that it is possibly related to jersey conflict.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(Response.java:921)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:592)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:603)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok(Response.java:638)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
```

```
<jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-proxy-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: what is the `javax.ws.rs-api` version in pom ?

Comment: Please write the `ResponseBuilder`  code that you are about to execute and getting error.

Comment: @lakshman it is 2.1

Comment: @VishwaRatna  i am just trying to return a version class with string version id.

Comment: Did my answer help? can you write some feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried different answers and solutions online, but the only thing that helped was using this mvn dependency conflict command

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=<conflicted groupId here>
```

I ran couple commands with glassfish and jersey and in the end i needed to remove the following from org.glassfish.jersey.media jar.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with jersey spring 4 dependency,

Use `jersey-spring3` instead `jersey-spring4` and if it still doesn't work, also downgrade version to 2.19

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
<version>2.19</version>
```

If you have still same issue, it's an old jar dependency, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54342244/junit-throwing-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-responseresponse) find it using `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: this didn't work, needed to run the full mvn dependency and resolve the conflicts