# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am trying to run a project in Java and came across the following issues:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4666)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:679)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:624)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:561)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4662b783.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$32(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4662b783$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$47cd6536.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4662b783.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
```

Other answers related to the question points to incompatible jackson libraries. However, this does not seem to be the case in this one as I have made all versions similar. The libraries used by the projects are:

```
**Referenced Libraries**
activation-1.1.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
bcprov-jdk15-1.46.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.10.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-io-2.6.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
esapi-2.0.1.jar
gson-2.8.5.jar
jasypt-1.9.2.jar
javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
jms-1.1.jar
jmxri-1.2.1.jar
jmxtools-1.2.1.jar
joda-time-1.6.2.jar
joda-time-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
mail-1.4.jar
not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9.jar
opensaml-2.5.3.jar
openws-1.4.4.jar
poi-3.11.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.0.jar
postgresql-42.2.5.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
velocity-1.5.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-3.0.2.jar
xmlsec-1.4.5.jar
xmltooling-1.3.4.jar


**WEB-INF/lib**
activation-1.1.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
bcprov-jdk15-1.46.jar
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.10.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-io-2.6.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
esapi-2.0.1.jar
gson-2.8.5.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.4.jar
jackson-core-2.9.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar
jasypt-1.9.2.jar
javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
jms-1.1.jar
jmxri-1.2.1.jar
jmxtools-1.2.1.jar
joda-time-1.6.2.jar
joda-time-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
mail-1.4.jar
not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9.jar
opensaml-2.5.3.jar
openws-1.4.4.jar
poi-3.11.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.0.jar
postgresql-42.2.5.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar
velocity-1.5.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-3.0.2.jar
xmlsec-1.4.5.jar
xmltooling-1.3.4.jar
```

I tried looking for pom.xml but it was not available.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:tree` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110881/3291897)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a suspicious library `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar` in your WEB-INF/lib. I'd kick it out, because it's probably shadowing `jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar`. The `addMixin` method exists since 2.5, so that `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar` must be 2.4 or older.

BTW, according to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.1.0.RELEASE, you should use jackson 2.9.7, but maybe 2.9.4 works, too.

Comment: Removing com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar solved the problem. Seems Jackson 2.9.4 is fine as i see no issue with the program