# Maven project sourcing old spring dependencies not part of the pom.xml in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

My maven java project is sourcing versions of spring libraries that are not defined in my pom.xml

My pom.xml does not have any references to v3.0.5 for spring dependencies.
A snippet of my pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

However when I do a `mvn clean -U compile package`, I am getting v3.0.5 of the spring libraries in my target:
[image]

Can someone help me with how I can remove the outdated/ out of version spring libraries which seem to be sourced 'automatically' without being included in my pom please.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to figure out which dependency is pulling in this versions by running `mvn depedency:tree`.

Comment: Thanks! I see where they are coming from now :)

Comment: @Turing85 In Eclipse, the _Maven POM Editor_ provides the _Dependency Hierarchy_ tab for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add an  element in the  element by which the problematic jar is getting fetched or included.these unwanted version of the libs are coming as transitive dependency from one of the mentioned dependency entry in your POM.xml. Use you eclipse or IntelliJ dependence tree to din out the jar that is bringing those transitive dependency and then exclude them fro that element .

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

For finding transitive dependency tree / list : [How can I view transitive dependencies of a Maven pom.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110782/how-can-i-view-transitive-dependencies-of-a-maven-pom-xml-file)