# Is there a way to see which artifacts in Central depend on a given artifact?

Tags: maven

I'm curious if there's a way that, given an artifact in Maven Central, one could find all other artifacts in Central which declare it as a dependency. I can't seem to find a way via the search interface or the Sonatype repository viewer.

Comment: Does this answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3342951/1083581

Comment: This site does a bit of that - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1.

Comment: @PaulGrime the indexing done by mvnrepository is the closest Tom's going to get (beyond downloading all POMs in Central and indexing them himself).  You might as well promote your comment to an answer.

Comment: @PaulGrime Grime Yeah, it looks like that's the closest thing. I'm surprised it's not indexed by Central proper though.