# junit test for spring 3.1.1 , hibernate 4.0.1 web application fail during creating session factory bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working on a web application spring 3.1.1 Release and hibernate 4.0.1 
my problem is when I deploy my project with jboss 7 everything work fine but know i want to add a junit test when I try to run it i get this exception :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ClientService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ClientDAO' while setting bean property 'ClientDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ClientDAO' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'SessionFactory' while setting bean property 'SessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>       at testClient.TestClient.setUpBeforeClass(TestClient.java:18)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ClientDAO' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'SessionFactory' while setting bean property 'SessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 31 more

 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 41 more

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:259)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 48 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected method not found: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(java.lang.Class)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethod(ClassUtils.java:627)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<clinit>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:68)
... 51 more
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
<spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
<artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>jboss</groupId>
<artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
<version>4.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
<artifactId>jta</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</dependency>            
<dependency>
<groupId>antlr</groupId>
<artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
<version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>          
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>     
<dependency>
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
<groupId>dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>

<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>           
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two hibernate libraries in dependencies of your project. One is declared explicitly and is of version 4.0.1. Another one is transitive via spring-orm and is of version 3.6 I guess (you can check exact version using [mvn dependency plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342908/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-for-an-artifact&ei=hH4HU9O2EfLe7AbMlIHYAg&usg=AFQjCNHZS8KOg03QwwXWMtF5MNLYixUFNg&sig2=uXg27AiVBOZwb5SNNyDUfA&bvm=bv.61725948,d.ZGU)).

On your application server hibernate 3.6 goes first in classpath and everything works smooth but in your test environment hibernate 4 goes first and it breaks tests.

Spring 3.1.1 requires hibernate 3.6 and is not compatible with hibernate 4 hence the error.

The fix for this is to either upgrade spring to version which supports hibernate 4 or to downgrade hibernate. In any case there is no need to specify hibernate explicitly in pom.xml (this will only make harm like the issue you have now).

Comment: but why everything works fine when i deploy my project ?

Comment: You must have different classpaths in this two cases. And on app server classpath includes correct version. How do you manage dependencies? Do you use maven?

Comment: Konowal ,yes i use maven i will post my pom.xml

Comment: Done but sorry  .. my first day here i don't know how to organise and edit the post with a good way

Comment: I've updated my answer with details on classpath order and multiple dependencies issue.