# Maven doesn't download jars from google repository

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, android-appcompat

I'm using eclispe with adt + maven to devellop an android app (what google has successfully made difficult enough)

But eclipse doens't recognieze google's support library for android, I added it to my pom like:

```
    <!-- ============= ANDROID =============== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
        <version>27.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support.constraint</groupId>
        <artifactId>constraint-layout</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>design</artifactId>
        <version>27.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-services-ads</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And at this same pom I added the google repository with:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>android-studio</id>
            <name>lixo</name>
            <url>https://maven.google.com</url>
            <!-- <url>file://C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository</url> -->
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

but eclipse [and also maven through shell command] isn't able to download the jars and my maven local repository gets

[image]

only the source code jar came... why? how can i hadle it?

Comment: Do all the dependency tags is placed inside <dependencies></dependencies> tag ?

Comment: The entries `.lastUpdated` indicate that you have some access/proxy/firewall issues or simply wrong names dependencies...

Comment: if it was any connection related issue it wouldn't download any other dependency, or even the sources.jar, but it does... so i disagree with the possibility of access/proxy/firewall being blocking the access, unless it is at google's side

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `<dependency>` elements are declared in a dependencies section, not in a [`<dependencyManagement>` one](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

And [check your dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3342908/6309), using `mvn dependency:tree` to validate that your expected artifact is indeed part of the dependencies needed by your project.

Only then can you check if the Google repo is taken into account or not.