# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. Cant get rid of binding

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

So,

once again im totally stuck with this error..
I've read few threads about the issue but cant fix it..

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.10.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

mvn dependency:tree gives following:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
```

For what i understand one instance is under starter-data-jpa
and in the folder .m2/ch/qos

but i cant delete that folder or the app wont start.

i cant seem to exclude it either.

```
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

After exclusion i run `mvn clean` and re-import all the dependecies but it still wont start.

And when i delete the whole

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

section, it now resides under `[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile`

according to `mvn dependency:tree` and app still wont start, same error.

So how do i get rid of this thing?

I have no idea how this happend. i have not added or removed anything in pom for weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to exclude all the logging framework so there wont be anymore unwanted loggers anywhere... it works

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem exists from a long time. The best way to deal with this is to follow the steps:

1. Look for maven dependencies. Search for log4j-slf4j. This library can be from multiple dependencies. I didn't want to remove spring-boot-starter-logging as it effects regular pretty spring logs. [How to get a dependency tree for an artifact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342908/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-for-an-artifact).

   > mvn dependency:tree
2. Exclude the dependency. You must be able to find one or more dependencies which has the same library. I had slf4j-log4j12 only in kafka-avro-serializer so I excluded from it. If your mvn dependency tree shows more thatn one make sure you exclude from all.

   ```
      <dependency>
           <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
           <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.0</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
   ```