# How to determine where is the version comes from in a mvn project?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

For a `mvn` project, we may use `dependencymanagement` to do version control. But the problem also come up, like,
The project's parent pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.YYY</groupId>
            <artifactId>YYY-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

if there is a jar, named `com.AAA:BBB`, is controlled both in `com.XXX:XXX-`dependencies and `com.YYY:YYY-dependencies`, how can we know which version maven will use finally ?
Is there a tool to help us to identify ? 
I have tried mvn dependency plugin, mvn help plugin and dependency analyzer in idea, no one works.

Comment: What do you mean with "I have tried mvn dependency plugin ... no one works"? Why does it not work for you? See [How to get a dependency tree for an artifact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342908/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-for-an-artifact)

Comment: Check `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: As I said, dependency:tree just tell us the final jar version, it can not tell us where the version comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Think in a different way. I guess you don't have to find out which version is getting from the other dependencies (transitive). You just need to make sure the version of AAA:BBB is coming in the project as expected.

Just add `com.AAA:BBB` (required dependency) in your pom.xml as an explicit dependency with your required version. So that it should look like below code

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.YYY</groupId>
            <artifactId>YYY-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.AAA</groupId>
            <artifactId>AAA-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>BBB</version> <!-- The version you expect -->
            <type>pom or jar whatever</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Make sure the two libraries you are consuming are runtime compatible with that version.

Comment: Yes, this is a way to fix. But I am just wondering whether there is a tool to tell us how maven determines the jar version.

We can not just override the jar but ignore the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules that maven follow to resolve transitive dependencies.
First is

```
A.v1
- B.v1
   - D.v1
- C.v1
   - E.v1
     - D.v2
```

Above D.v1 will be consumed as the nearest dependency to D is A-B-D.

```
A.v1
- B.v1
   - D.v1
- C.v1
   - D.v2
```

In above, as per nearest dependency rule both are at same level, so now the dependency included (written) first will be consumed, ie. D.v1.