# Get list of dependencies for Maven artifact in repository

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I would like to determine the list of dependencies of an artifact in a Maven repository.

My best approach so far: Download the POM, construct a pseudo-project that just contains this POM and run `dependency:list` with the appropriate parameters.

Since Maven itself does the same thing (determines dependencies of artifacts to construct a dependency tree), I wonder if there is a more direct way. I would to run it from Java, so any Java method or Maven goal would be fine.

Comment: Would this help you issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342908/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-for-an-artifact

Comment: @Dinnerspy Sounds like a similar question. Unfortunately, the answers are only medium promising...