# Gradle how to get dependency tree for a particular artifact

Tags: gradle

So, in maven we can get the dependency tree of a single artifact as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40025428/5655767

Is there an equivalent in gradle? I've been searching for a few hours now and can't find anything at all

EDIT: Please note that this question is different from [Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree/50231453#50231453) as I would like to know if I can do something similar to `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]` in gradle to avoid looking through all dependencies.  None of the answers in the question above solve this, they all aim to listing all dependencies in project or module as the smallest form of granularity

Comment: No, this lists all dependencies, I want to list a single one, as in answer attached to the question, this is not a duplicate of the question you've posted

Comment: You are referring to Maven and artifacts, those use to be modules or whole project in Maven specified by artifact and group ID's. Link's i have posted provide solution to find dependency graph for single Gradle module (subproject or whole project) as well. Are you sure that those link's doesn't answer your question ?

Comment: No, a module is a higher form of granularity than a single dependency, please check edit that I've added to question