# scala log4j vulnerability

Tags: scala, maven, log4j

I am using below scala dependencies in pom.xml but it is giving log4j vulnerability error.

```
 <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.major.version>2.11</scala.major.version>
        <scala.minor.version>2.11.12</scala.minor.version>
        <gridgain.version>8.7.8</gridgain.version>
        <ignite.version>2.7.0</ignite.version>
        <spark.version>2.3.0</spark.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.4.0</spring.boot.version>
        <maven-release-plugin-version>2.5.3</maven-release-plugin-version>
        <maven-assembly-plugin-version>3.1.1</maven-assembly-plugin-version>
 </properties>



 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
                <artifactId>gridgain-core</artifactId>
                <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
                <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-log4j2</artifactId>
                <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.scala-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-logging_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.minor.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.minor.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>2.5.3</version>   
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <!-- work-around for https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8358 -->
                            <arg>-nobootcp</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.5.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
 <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>iterator</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <folder>../deployment/config</folder>
                                <pluginExecutors>
                                    <pluginExecutor>
                                        <goal>single</goal>
                                        <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>${maven-assembly-plugin-version}</version>
                                        </plugin>
                                        <configuration>
                                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                                     
 </configuration>
                                    </pluginExecutor>
                                </pluginExecutors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

It is giving below error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.0.1:compile (default) on project Execution default of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.0.1:compile failed: Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.0.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.8.1 /org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1.jar. Error code 403, Requested item is quarantined -> [Help 1]

Which dependency internally using log4j-core-2.8.1.jar and How to update log4j to latest 2.17.0?

Comment: You probably need to check the [dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3342951/4803842) and see what dependency brings log4j

Comment: It looks like the dependency comes from `ignite-log4j2` but there is no version of `ignite-log4j2` released with correct log4j version. You can override it by specifying a dependency directly to [log4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.17.0) in your pom file

Answer (score 0):

try using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.alchim31.maven/scala-maven-plugin/4.5.6

this is the latest that internally use the latest log4j 2.17