# Why is Log4j 1.2.16 automatically downloaded during Maven update

Tags: java, maven, log4j, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am working on a JAVA Maven project, which is mainly configured using logback with slf4j. I can't see any Log4j dependency in my Maven dependency tree, means Log4j is not transitively coming from any of my pom XML component. I am assuming that, it is coming from some Maven plugins, I am using eclipse editor. I want to remove that vulnerable Log4j component completely as I am using different logging framework. Is there any way to know to resolve this issue, means to stop downloading Log4j during Maven update? Is there any way to know the Library/plugin name which is fetching Log4j. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Ritesh

Comment: Use Maven to generate a dependency tree and see which dependency is transitively including that log4j2 version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342908/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-for-an-artifact

Comment: Which Maven version, which versions of the plugins are you using (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using Maven compiler plugin version 3.11.0, but is there any way to know the plugin name with version which is fetching Log4j transitively. I am not using any Log4j dependency in pom XML and my project Maven dependency tree is not showing any Log4j component. I am sure that Log4j is being downloaded in my local repository location due to some Maven plugins. Maven update downloading Log4j automatically. Please advise.

Comment: The maven-compiler-plugin is not the only plugin... there are a lot more .. maven-resources-plugin, maven-surefire/failsafe-plugin, maven-install-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin... maven-jar-plugin/maven-ear-plugin/ etc.. check them all...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, I just want to stop downloading log4j in my local repository without my current plugins version upgrade. Means after Maven update my local repo Log4j folder should be empty. That's it. Can I do that. I tried with maven-enforcer-plugin to stop downloading Log4j, but have no luck. Thanks!

Comment: I know what you like to achieve but you seemed to ignore my question... you are not posting a full pom file, not given information like which Maven versions and plugin versions (only for one plugin) you are using what kind of project it is ? Spring ? Spring Boot ? Quarkus?

Comment: So I bet blindly that you are using maven-site-plugin somewhere in your build ?

Answer (score 0):

- Check Maven Plugin:
  Some Maven plugins may also bring in Log4j as a dependency. Review the plugins configured in your pom.xml or in your IDE configuration (like Eclipse settings). Look for any plugins related to logging or build processes that might be pulling in Log4j.

Remove or update the plugins accordingly. For example, if you are using Eclipse, check the Eclipse Run Configurations and Maven configurations to ensure there are no unnecessary dependencies.

- Check IDE Integration:
  Some IDEs have their own way of managing dependencies. In Eclipse, right-click on the project, go to "Properties," and check the "Java Build Path" and "Maven" settings. Ensure that there are no unnecessary dependencies, especially Log4j.

Comment: I am using Maven compiler plugin version 3.11.0, but is there any way to know the plugin name with version which is fetching Log4j transitively. I am not using any Log4j dependency in pom XML and my project Maven dependency tree is not showing any Log4j component. I am sure that Log4j is being downloaded in my local repository location due to some Maven plugins. Maven update downloading Log4j automatically. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out exactly which artifacts being downloaded by Maven Plugins is to build against an empty cache `$HOME/.m2/repository`. But it is not necessary to delete global user cache.

You can create a cache which is local to your project for testing purposes like this:

```
mvn -B clean verify -Dmaven.repo.local=$(pwd)/.repo >mvn.log 2>&1
```

The generated log file `mvn.log` contains the full output during the build which includes the downoaded artifacts of your project or the maven plugins. The file will contain lines like this:

```
[INFO] --- clean:3.3.2:clean (default-clean) @ dependency-analysis ---
[INFO] Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.pom (8.7 kB at 1.7 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/13/plexus-13.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/13/plexus-13.pom (27 kB at 2.7 MB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from nexus: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/4.0.0/plexus-utils-4.0.0.jar (192 kB at 38 MB/s)
[INFO] Deleting /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/examples/dep-analysis/target
```

That will show you that the [`maven-clean-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/) requires a dependency like `plexus-utils` etc.

Based on such log file you can easily identify which plugin will download particular artifacts.