NoSuchMethodError Charsets.toCharset() between Apache poi and commons in IntelliJ unit test
I'm using Apache poi 5.2.3 in a neo4j plugin for neo4j 4.4.30 using openjdk temurin-11.0.22. We use commons-io 2.15.1.
Edit: The problem primarily (only?) occurs when running a unit test in IntelliJ directly from the context menu in the code. Perhaps the real problem is that IntelliJ isn't sufficiently aware of which dependencies the code is supposed to use.
I originally used import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook to export data to Excel (because that's what business users want; you know how it is...), but I'm trying to switch to org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook to support streaming (because business users want more data).
When I switch those two classes, I get
NoSuchMethodError: 'java.nio.charset.Charset org.apache.commons.io.Charsets.toCharset(java.nio.charset.Charset, java.nio.charset.Charset)'

This makes no sense, because commons-io 2.15.1 does contain that function.
I do notice SXSSFWorkbook does something with CharSets that XSSFWorkbook doesn't (not sure why), but I can't find the exact call. Even so, commons-io 2.15.1 should be fine for poi 5.2.3 as far as I can tell.
So I'm baffled why this isn't working. I'm clearly not enough of a dependency guru to figure this out. Any idea where I should be looking?
Edit: I noticed that ~/.m2/repository does contain several versions of commons-io, including 2.5, 2.6, 2.11 and 2.13, but where do they come from?
Then I remembered mvn dependency:tree  -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-io, which gives:
[INFO] com.example:excel-procedures:jar:0.34.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.example:project-neo4j-core:jar:0.34.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.15.1:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.example:validation:jar:0.34.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.15.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:4.4.30:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:4.4.30:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.15.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-record-storage-engine:jar:4.4.30:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.15.1)
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:jar:4.4.30:provided
[INFO] |     \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:provided - omitted for conflict with 2.15.1)
[INFO] +- org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:jar:4.4.30:test
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:test-jar:tests:4.4.30:test
[INFO] |     \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:test - omitted for conflict with 2.15.1)
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.15.1)
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.15.1)
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.26.0:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.15.1:provided - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.15.1:compile

But what does this mean? No 2.5 or 2.6, and all 2.11 is omitted.
Edit2: Did some more digging, looking at what maven actually downloads, and despite dependency:tree denying it, maven does download several versions of commons-io:
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) 
Downloading from central: https://our-repo.example.com:443/artifactory/our-repo-maven/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar

[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile)
Downloading from central: https://our-repo.example.com:443/artifactory/our-repo-maven/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar

[INFO] --- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test)
Downloaded from central: https://our-repo.example.com:443/artifactory/our-repo-maven/commons-io/commons-io/2.12.0/commons-io-2.12.0.jar 

So I guess that explains where they come from, but why doesn't this show up in mvn dependency:tree, and how do I prevent these from downloading wrong versions?
Edit: One vital detail I may have omitted is that this is a sub-project under a parent pom, and all dependencies are handled by the parent pom. Apparently dependency overrides in the parent pom don't always work for the sub projects, and this probably caused the problem.
I'd love to see (and will accept and upvote) a more thorough explanation of how this works and why maven vs JUnit matters, but putting dependency overrides in the child pom seems to fix the issue.

In my experience, the most probable reason is that you are using an older version of poi (or another library) that does not have this method

Yup, you have a version of org.apache.commons.io.Charsets in your classpath that does not. It doesn't matter that you 'checked it' and found that 'it does' - it does not, that is what that error means, it's not lying. If you checked it and you found that it does, that merely means there is also a version of that class on the classpath that does have it. But java doesn't try to merge 2 conflicting versions, obviously. It picks the first one it finds. Solution: Scour your dependencies, upgrade the straggler.

How can I verify this and how would I fix it? My pom.xml says commons-io 2.15.1, which according to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/Charsets.html has the function that's needed. Where does the other one come from?

I do notice several older versions of commons-io, 2.5, 2.6, 2.11 and 2.13, in ~/.m2/repository, updated today, so that sounds like you're right, but where do they come from and is it possible to ensure that the correct one is being used?

You need to look at the dependency tree to see where the conflicting version comes from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342908/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-for-an-artifact

I tried (added the output to the question), but I can't find any conflicts there.

You seem to be mostly correct in the understanding that 2.15.0 should be the version that is getting used. There are a few scenarios where it may not be getting picked correctly. Perhaps for some reason the runtime classpath does not contain the correct commons-io version. Howe are you running your application. If it is within a container (e.g. Tomcat) then check the actual package that is deployed and also check the container default libraries (e.g. Tomcat_Home/lib)

When I get this error, I'm running a specific unit test in my IDE (IntelliJ). Normally, this code is loaded as a neo4j plugin running in a kubernetes cluster. There, the change from XSSFWorkbook to SXSSFWorkbook also breaks, but it's much harder to debug why.

I've tried overriding the dependency explicitly for the maven plugins, but that doesn't work; they still download the old versions. But I think IntelliJ shouldn't be looking at those old versions at all; I think the problem only occurs when I run the unit test directly from the code; using maven to run them works fine. So it's really an IntelliJ problem, I think.

I still don't know why Java uses the wrong commons-io, but I figured out how to override it. This project is one of several under a shared parent pom, and all dependencies are handled in that parent pom. Apparently maven understands that just fine (under the best circumstances at least; sometimes it goes wrong), but JUnit does not.
IntelliJ uses JUnit directly to run individual tests, and for that it apparently does consult the sub pom but not the parent pom. Putting the override for commons-io in the sub pom fixes the issue.
I still don't understand why, and would appreciate if anyone could explain that, but at least I've got a solution. Or a sufficiently practical workaround at least.
